# SQL Complex join not giving distinct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables :-

Table1:-

```
ID1

1
1
1
1
4
5
```

Table2:-

```
Id2

  2
  2
  1
  1
  1
  8
```

I want to show all the ID2 from table2 which are present in ID1 of table1 by using joins

I used :-

```
select ID2 from Table2 t2 left join Table1 t1
on t2.Id2=t1.Id1
```

But this was giving repeated result as :-

```
Id2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

It should show me 1 as 3 times only as it is present in Table2 3 times.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're matching the value `1` with 4 rows on `Table1` and 3 rows on `Table2` that's why you're seeing 12 rows. You need an additional `JOIN` condition. You can add a `ROW_NUMBER` and do an `INNER JOIN` to achieve your desired result.

```
WITH Cte1 AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Table1
),
Cte2 AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id2 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Table2
)
SELECT c2.Id2
FROM Cte2 c2
INNER JOIN Cte1 c1
    ON c1.Id1 = c2.Id2
    AND c1.rn = c2.rn
```

However, you can achieve the desired result without using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 t2 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.Id1 = t2.Id2
)
```

Comment: WHERE EXISTS HAS SOLVED MY PROBLEM.. THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 2):

It's the expected behavior of Join Operation. It will match every row from the two tables, so you will get 12 rows containing value 1 in result of join query.

You can use below query to get desired result.

```
select ID2 from Table2 t2 WHERE ID2 IN (SELECT ID1 FROM Table1 t1)
```

Comment: might want to add a distinct to your first select

Comment: If I am not mistaken, SQL IN Clause operates on distinct values only. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: IN will slow down the speed thats why I thought of using joins, because there is going to be large amount of data

Comment: You are absolutely spot on about IN performance issue. But it's not possible retrieve distinct values from Table2 using SIMPLE JOIN operation. With sample data at my end, it's performing nested loop semi join. If you have an index on ID columns, it may help to improve the performance of query.

Comment: I meant distinct on the first select from `Table2`

Answer (score 2):

```html
select id2 from table2 t2 where exists ( select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id1 = t2.id2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join logic works fine, the problem is each of your ID2 is matching against all ID1s.  A simple solution would be to join with a table of distinct ID1s to avoid this duplication.

```
select 
t2.ID2 
from Table2 t2 
left join (select distinct * from Table1) t1
on t1.Id1=t2.Id2 
where t1.ID1 is not null
;
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/IYRXLD77350)

This will select your entire ID2 list with ID1 populated in a column.  ID1 is null where there was no match.  Select your ID2 column from this table but just don't pull null values (with where clause):